# Nondeterministic finite automata with multiple accept/failure states

Tags: theory, finite-automata, compiler-theory, computation-theory, automata-theory

I'm having trouble making accept states for an NFA for situations that would be easy with a regular expression or an (apparently equivalent) deterministic finite automata.

For instance, what if the machine only accepts if none of the states are possible at the end? You could use the powerset construction to make a DFA where the accepting state is the empty set. The only way I can think to do this with the NFA is to make every state "accepting", and then flip it at the end so an accept is actually a failure.

Even worse, what if you had 6 states and want to check if, say, you're potentially in all of states {0,1,2}, but definitely *not* in {3,4,5}? Again, this would be easy with the DFA.

Is there an easy way to tweak NFAs for these cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Every DFA is a NFA too. So if you can do something using DFA, then you are done! You did it using NFA.

Comment: Ah... so does that mean it's not possible to, say, AND together accept states in a NFA? The annoying thing is that I can model the problem quite nicely as an NFA, but I can't make a proper accept state. But you're right, I can definitely find an associated DFA that works (which is an NFA...).

Comment: just learn about NFA to DFA